# Arithmetic and geometric progressions based question

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Q. Let a, b, c be positive integers such that b/a is an integer. If a, b, c are in geometric progression and the arithmetic mean of a, b, c is b+2,  the value of (a²+a-14) /(a+1) is..?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! Nice question. Have you tried solving it? Did you encounter any difficulties?

Comment: Let $a = x$, $b=xd$, and $c=xd^2$. So $d^2-2d+1=\frac6x\to(d-1)^2=\frac6x$

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $d=b/a$ so $a+b+c=3ad+6=a(1+d+d^2)$, i.e. $6=(1-d)^2a$. The only square dividing $6$ is $1$, so $a=6$. Hence $\frac{a^2+a-14}{a+1}=a-\frac{14}{a+1}=6-2=4$.